# Javascript returning "empty" strings inside an array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a function that returns a "staircase". The output needs to look like this:

```
  var staircase5 = [
        "    #",
        "   ##",
        "  ###",
        " ####",
        "#####"
    ]
```

The code I've written so far is:

```
function staircase (valueA){
    const array1 = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < valueA; i++){
        let cicle = valueA[i];
        let step = " #".repeat(cicle);
        array1.push(step)
    }
console.log(array1);
}
```

When I run the code in VS Code, `console.log(staircase(3));` , this is the result:

```
[ '', '', '' ]
undefined
```

Any clue as to why it is returning the strings as ' ' instead of '#'? And why is it not really repeating?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Where do you call your function?

Comment: Show us how you are calling the function please.

Comment: If `valueA` is a string or array, i assume it should be `i < valueA.length`

Comment: @slappy based on the output, it seems `valueA = 3`.

Comment: @VLAZ: Then his `valueA[i]` would seem out of place.

Comment: I've updated the question to show how I'm calling the function: console.log(staircase(3));

Comment: @slappy most definitely.

Comment: If you are passing `3`, then `valueA` is `3`, which is not an array or array-like object, so passing an index to it `valueA[i]` returns `undefined`. If you open your developer tools and look at the console, you'll see an error about it.

Comment: @LuisArgüelles: This is a *great* opportunity for some [rubber duck debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  When you define the `circle` variable, what do you expect `valueA[i]` to be and why?

Comment: @David: As valueA is a number, I'm expecting the for loop to count from 0 up to valueA. Then valueA[i] should be the number it has counted up to so far. I'm really new to JS, and I might be doing it all wrong...

Comment: As I said, you can't pass an index to a number. Just `i` will give you the number of the current loop iteration, not `valueA[i]`.

Comment: @LuisArgüelles please look at my answer. Is it what you wanted?

Comment: @ScottMarcus: I get it, thanks a lot.

Comment: @DominikMatis: Not really, hev1's answer works better for me. Thanks a lot anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently trying to treat `valueA`, which is a number, like an array. If you loop from 1 to valueA, then each step should be the space repeated value - i times concatenated with the # character repeated i times.

```js
function staircase (valueA){
    const array1 = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= valueA; i++){
        let step = " ".repeat(valueA - i) + "#".repeat(i);
        array1.push(step)
    }
    return array1;
}
console.log(staircase(5))
```

Comment: This is working for me! Thanks a lot. As soon as I can accept the answer I will.

Comment: @LuisArgüelles No problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use padding.

```js
const staircase = count => {
    let array1 = [];
    let step = ""
    for (let i = 0; i < count; i++){
        step = "#".repeat(i+1);
        array1 = [...array1, step.padStart(count, ' ')]
    }
    console.log(array1);
}

staircase(5)
```

Comment: Read the comments under the question. The OP is trying to pull an index of a number. You've provided a working answer without answering the question as to what is wrong.

Comment: "I've updated the question to show how I'm calling the function: console.log(staircase(3)); – Luis Argüelles 3 mins ago" ... really?

Answer (score 0):

If you need your output look like this:

```
  var staircase5 = [
        "    #",
        "   ##",
        "  ###",
        " ####",
        "#####"
    ]
```

Your function should be like this:

```
function staircase (valueA){
    const array1 = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= valueA; i++){
        let step = " ".repeat(valueA-i)+"#".repeat(i);
        array1.push(step)
    }
  return array1
}
```

### Explanation

In your function:

> ```
>  function staircase (valueA){
>      const array1 = [];
>      for (let i = 0; i < valueA; i++){
>          let cicle = valueA[i];
>          let step = " #".repeat(cicle);
>          array1.push(step)
>      }
>      console.log(array1); 
>   }
> ```

I supposse you are calling the function like this:

```
var staircase5 = staircase(5);
```

In this line: `let cicle = valueA[i];` you are trying to take each value of valueA (as an array) and in this line: `for (let i = 0; i < valueA; i++)` you are using it as a number.

and in this line: `let step = " #".repeat(cicle);` if your valuaA is equal to 5 your output will be:

```
[
   " # # # # #",
   " # # # # #",
   " # # # # #",
   " # # # # #",
   " # # # # #"
]
```

In my solution I use `i` in `" ".repeat(valueA-i)+"#".repeat(i);` to iterate between the values that you need to make the array.

When `i` increment `" ".repeat(valueA-i)` will render less spaces. (ie: if i=2 and valueA=5, step will be: "   ", 3 spaces)

Test:

```js
function staircase (valueA){
    const array1 = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= valueA; i++){
        let step = " ".repeat(valueA-i)+"#".repeat(i);
        array1.push(step)
    }
  return array1
}

var staircase5 = staircase(5);

console.log(staircase5)
```

Comment: A good answer is more than just posting working code. You should explain the problem and how your solution solves it so that others can learn something.